# How to access a Heroku database from pgAdmin4

Tags: heroku, pgadmin-4

I want to access Heroku database from `pgAdmin4` on my local machine.

What I did is the following steps（However, it did not work）

1. First, I obtained the necessary information with the following *command* :

   ```
   heroku **config**
   ```
2. Next, enter the information from (1)  into the following form in `pgAdmin4` :

   ```
   [setting,including Host,port,ysername..][1]
   ```
3. After configuring the settings, I seem to be able to access Heroku, but I cannot open the database.

   （Each table icon has a `X` (cross) in the upper right corner. Click on any icon to display the message）

   [Icon with a cross in the upper right corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2ky5.png)
   [Indicates an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgO5V.png)

Please let me know how to clear it.

Comment: You've connected to the database _server_, but it hosts databases for several users' apps. You can't access other users' databases. Which one is _yours_? Make sure to try opening the right one.

Comment: I had clicked on the icon of another database.
I scrolled down, found the icon for my database, and
I was able to open it.
Thank you!